# Store Array Data to Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays

I'm trying to store data from some arrays into the database but only the last index of the arrays were stored. I know I need to fix the looping part but I've no idea how to. Below is the code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["Mon1"].Value = newTA.MonAry[i];
            cmd.Parameters["Tue1"].Value = newTA.TueAry[i];
            cmd.Parameters["Wed1"].Value = newTA.WedAry[i];
            cmd.Parameters["Thu1"].Value = newTA.ThuAry[i];
            cmd.Parameters["Fri1"].Value = newTA.FriAry[i];
        }
```

Comment: and where are you executing the command ?

Comment: why are you looping this? the last value only will be there all are overwritten since the loop is working five times

Comment: @Shekar_Pro Command is executed after the loop together with other Parameters which are not needed to be in the loop.

Comment: @NDC, Is there any other way where I can store all the data from array into database without looping? I'm not sure. Please let me know if there's another better solution.

Comment: @Ye Myat Aung : which database are you using ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to create and execute the command inside the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Some Connection String"))
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO foo (...) VALUES (...)";
        cmd.Parameters["Mon1"].Value = newTA.MonAry[i];
        cmd.Parameters["Tue1"].Value = newTA.TueAry[i];
        cmd.Parameters["Wed1"].Value = newTA.WedAry[i];
        cmd.Parameters["Thu1"].Value = newTA.ThuAry[i];
        cmd.Parameters["Fri1"].Value = newTA.FriAry[i];
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I should write individual command text for each parameters?

Comment: @Ye Myat Aung, you should execute a different SQL query for each item in the array.

Comment: You don't need to recreate the command in each loop if the SQL command is going to be the same, you can reuse it. Create the command before the loop. Inside the loop fill the parameters and execute the command. When the loop is finished close the connection.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using sqlserver then you can pass this as table type parameter  so that mutiple rows can be inserted [see this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Comment: I've figured out a workaround by converting the values in the array to strings and store them in the server with by using += operator.

It would work for me since the data in the arrays are like '00000' or '01001' etc.